# How to match multiple columns of data when some columns are empty?

Tags: python, regex

I've to match the below pattern.

```
98.40.1.0/12     104.12.1.222                           0 37430 9123 817 i

                 44.156.112.10            0              0 2224 6336 711 i

                 51.134.121.9                           0 7456 8936 1222 900 i
```

I wrote the expression as below:

```
\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)(?:\d+\s+|\s+)(?:\d+\s+|\s+)(.*)
```

, but it's not working for all the three lines because second and third lines have no data in the first column.

Can someone please suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: And how are you expecting to match "columns" with regex? You're using the wrong tool.

Comment: its not a column, i wrote column word just to differentiate the pattern what i mentioned above.
Its just a text file O/P that i need to parse.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I meant is that regex is not a parser. You're using the wrong tool.

Comment: Please be exact about your desired result IN YOUR QUESTION.  It is okay to reply to comments under an answer, but if you have new detail that are vital to the question, please do a question edit so that the full story in all inside the question.

Comment: i'll be using it in textfsm a python module to parse the O/P

Answer (score 0):

Following regex works (tested in python):

```
((\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)([\/]\d*)?)(\s*\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)*((\s*\d*)*)
```

This solution works only with assumption: The pattern "98.40.1.0/12" will only be at the start, rest of other will be of pattern "104.12.1.222"

Output - should only use match at position 1, 4, and 5:

```
Match 1
1.  98.40.1.0/12
2.  98.40.1.0
3.  /12
4.  104.12.1.222
5.  0 37430 9123 817
6.  Empty

Match 2
1.  44.156.112.10
2.  44.156.112.10
3.  None
4.  None
5.  0 0 2224 6336 711
6.  Empty

Match 3
1.  51.134.121.9
2.  51.134.121.9
3.  None
4.  None
5.  0 7456 8936 1222 900
6.  Empty
```

Comment: actually what i want is:
Match 1
1.  98.40.1.0/12
2.  
3. 
4.  104.12.1.222
5.  37430 9123 817 i
6.

Match 2
1.  
2.  44.156.112.10
3.  
4.  
5.  2224 6336 711 i
6. 

Similarly, match 3.

Comment: Means you want to remove "0" from match at position 5. Correct?

Comment: yes, would like to remove 0 and for match 2 and 3 i shouldn't get anything at 1.

Comment: @PeterSmith This will work `((\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)[\/]\d*)?(\s*\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)* (\s*0*)*((\s*\d*)*)`

Answer (score 0):

It is a good approach:

- To capture what you want using capturing groups, and parts
  to "omit" should be between these groups.
- If the same pattern occurs multiple times, then:

  - define a named pattern **once**,
  - call it multiple times.

Try a solution compliant with the above rules (for readability I split it
into 2 lines):

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<IP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))
^((?&IP)\/\d+)?\s+((?&IP))(?:\s+0)+ ((?:\d+ )+\d+)
```

with options `g` (*global*) and `m` (*multi-line*).

Description of individual parts:

- `(?(DEFINE)(?<IP>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))` - Define a named capturing
  group (group #1, name `IP`). Here it is only a definition, this
  group (so far) does not capture anything.
- `^` - Start of a line (not the whole string, due to `m` option).
- `((?&IP)\/\d+)?` - Capturing group #2, including:

  - a "call" of `IP` group,
  - a slash and sequence of digits,
  - all this optional (`?` at the end).
- `\s+` - A sequence of spaces.
- `((?&IP))` - Capturing group #3 - another "call" of `IP` group.
- `(?:\s+0)+` - Non-capturing group - spaces and `0`, repeated
  several times.
- - A space after the last `0` to skip.
- `((?:\d+ )+\d+)` - Capturing group #4, including:

  - a sequence of digits and a space, repeated several times,
  - the last sequence of digits.

This regex captures:

- From row 1:

  - `98.40.1.0/12` - group 2,
  - `104.12.1.222` - group 3,
  - `37430 9123 817` - group 4.
- From row 2:

  - group 2 caught nothing,
  - `44.156.112.10` - group 3,
  - `2224 6336 711` - group 4.
- From row 3:

  - group 2 caught nothing,
  - `51.134.121.9` - group 3,
  - `7456 8936 1222 900` - group 4.